# What does the order of R's classes cause?

Tags: r, function, class

[Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) states that a class assignment `class(x) <- c("A", "B")` does the following:

> As discussed in the next section, R looks for methods in the order in
>   which they appear in the class vector. So in this example, it would be
>   like class A inherits from class B - if a method isn’t defined for A,
>   it will fall back to B. However, if you switched the order of the
>   classes, the opposite would be true!

Here, what I understand:

```
print.mytest <- function(x, ...) {
  cat(paste0("Just a test for class mytest: ", x, "\n")
}

x <- 1
print(class(x))
# [1] "numeric"
print(x)
# [1] 1
class(x) <- c("mytest")
print(class(x))
# [1] "mytest"
print(x)
# [1] "Just a test for class mytest: 1"
```

Here is, what I don't understand: I expected the use of class `numeric` but it is never used.
Thus, I would expect an output of `[1] 1` in the second case.

```
x <- 1
print(class(x))
# [1] "numeric"
class(x) <- c(class(x), "mytest")
print(class(x))
# [1] "numeric" "mytest" 
print(x) # Not understood (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html)
# [1] "Just a test for class mytest: 1"

x <- 1
print(class(x))
# [1] "numeric"
class(x) <- c("mytest", class(x))
print(class(x))
# [1] "mytest"  "numeric"
print(x) # Not understood...
# [1] "Just a test for class mytest: 1"
```

The docs `?class` also state

> When a generic function fun is applied to an object with class
>   attribute c("first", "second"), the system searches for a function
>   called fun.first and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no
>   such function is found, a function called fun.second is tried. If no
>   class name produces a suitable function, the function fun.default is
>   used (if it exists).

---

Thank's to the answer below

```
x <- 1
print(class(x))
class(x) <- c("mytest2", "mytest")
print(class(x))
print(x)
# Just a test for class mytest2:  1 
x <- 1
print(class(x))
class(x) <- c("mytest", "mytest2")
print(class(x))
print(x)
# Just a test for class mytest:  1
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a `print` method defined for `numeric`, so in either case it falls back on the first one that is defined.

Comment: @AndrewGustar You are right, it uses `print.default`, but "the first one" in the example `class(x) <- c(class(x), "mytest")` is `"numeric"` but the output is not `[1] 1`! Thus you agree, it's a good question? ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing it only uses `print.default` if it cannot find a `print` method for any of the classes, rather than just if it can't find one for the first class.

Comment: @AndrewGustar See my edit. even `?class` states "When a generic function fun is applied to an object with class attribute c("first", "second"), the system searches for a function called fun.first". I don't understand...

Comment: It cycled though. There isn't a print.numeric function so it went to the next option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only uses the default method if none of the methods for the classes in the class vector are found.  In the question there is no `print.numeric` but there is a `print.mytest` so it is used in both cases.  It never looks for a `print.default` because it can find a method among those listed in the class vector.

That is, it looks at the first element of `class(x)` and if in this case a `print` method for that class is found it uses it.  If not it moves on to the second element of `class(x)` and looks for a `print` method of that class.  If it is found it uses it.  If there were only two elements of `class(x)` and methods for neither were found then it would use the default method.

In the case where `class(x)` is `c("numeric", "mytest")` there is no `print.numeric` method so it looks for a `print.mytest` and finds it so it uses it.

In the case where `class(x)` is `c("mytest", "numeric")` it finds `print.mytest` and so it uses it.

Thus in both cases `print.mytest` is the method chosen.

Comment: The answer here describes the same mechanism as in the quote from `?class` but relates it specifically to your example.

Comment: Ok, so if methods are used which you do not expect, it is most likely to a missing `function.default`. Thanks a lot...